# Как написать функцию на с++ лучше с точки зрения производительности?

Tags: java, c++, матрицы, stl

Я переписываю программу с джавы на с++ и со следующей функцией возникли проблемы:

```java
private static int[][] collectMatrix(int[][] a11, int[][] a12, int[][] a21, int[][] a22) {
    int n = a11.length;
    int[][] a = new int[n << 1][n << 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(a11[i], 0, a[i], 0, n);
        System.arraycopy(a12[i], 0, a[i], n, n);
    System.arraycopy(a21[i], 0, a[i + n], 0, n);
        System.arraycopy(a22[i], 0, a[i + n], n, n);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Я переписал её следующим образом:

```cpp
vector<vector<int>> collectMatrix(vector<vector<int>> a11, vector<vector<int>> a12, vector<vector<int>> a21, vector<vector<int>> a22) {
    int n = a11.size();
    vector<vector<int>> a;
    a.resize(n << 1,vector<int>(n << 1));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i].insert(a[i].begin(), a11[i].begin(), a11[i].end());
        a[i].insert(a[i].begin() + n, a12[i].begin(), a12[i].end());
        a[i+n].insert(a[i+n].begin(), a21[i].begin(), a21[i].end());
        a[i+n].insert(a[i+n].begin() + n, a22[i].begin(), a22[i].end());
    }
    return a;
}
```

Но этот вариант через vector кажется мне медленным, поскольку я засекал время выполнения на обоих языках (не конкретно этих функций правда, но больше нечему тормозить), и оказалось, что на с++ медленнее, чем на java, чего быть не должно!! Поэтому я хочу изменить вариант с vector (массив с переменной длинной) на что-то быстрее, а именно на массив статического размера, поскольку в моей программе не обязательна переменная длина, статика тоже подойдёт, но не знаю как лучше это сделать. Круто, если поможете кусочком кода.

Comment: Статический в каком смысле? Вы имеете в виду "не динамический" (т.е. локальную переменную типа `int a[5][10]`), или статическую переменную (типа `static int a[5][10]`)?

Comment: Просто вернуть массив можно обернув его в структуру, можно передать адрес на массив-приемники и скопировать.

Comment: @Harry, не динамический имею в виду. Я прикрепил код к вопросу.

Comment: Объекты динамического размера через стек не возвращаются. Можно только массивы статического размера, заключённую в структуру.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, я матрицу статического размера и хочу вернуть из функции или я что-то не понял о чём вы. Можно ли пример кода?

Comment: Тогда что значит "не динамический"? `int matr[n][n];` - по хорошему, это не должно компилироваться (хотя на некоторых компиляторах с дефолтными настройками работает), размер массива должен быть известен во время компиляции. По этой же причине `std::array` не подойдет, лучше возьмите `std::vector`.

Comment: В С++ такой код не сработает. Размер массива должен быть известен во время компиляции. Просто вернуть массив нельзя, но, как вам уже написали, можно завернуть его в структуру, или скопировать в переданный в качестве аргумента массив-приемник.

Comment: @Harry, я решил задать вопрос по-другому.

Comment: Сформулируйте, пожалуйста, сверхзадачу - словом, что должна делать функция.

Comment: Задавайте новый вопрос, а не редактируйте старый

Comment: @Harry, функция собирает квадратную матрицу a размером n x n из 4 квадратных матриц a11, a12, a21, a22 размером n/2 x n/2. (Просто склеивает 4 одинаковых по размеру матрицы в одну матрицу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы переписал ваш вариант с векторами следующим образом:

```
vector<vector<int>> collectMatrix(const vector<vector<int>>& a11,
                                  const vector<vector<int>>& a12,
                                  const vector<vector<int>>& a21,
                                  const vector<vector<int>>& a22)
{
    int n = a11.size();
    vector<vector<int>> a(2*n, vector<int>(2*n));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            a[i][j] = a11[i][j];
            a[i+n][j] = a21[i][j];
            a[i][j+n] = a12[i][j];
            a[i+n][j+n] = a22[i][j];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Для простоты не стал добавлять проверки, что все входные массивы одного размера `nxn`.

Comment: понял, спасибо!)

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устроил - можете его принять :) - птичка слева от ответа.